# Spark count number of words with in group by

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset

```
+----------+--------+------------+
|        id|    date|       errors|
+----------+--------+------------+
|1         |20170319|      error1|
|1         |20170319|      error2|
|1         |20170319|      error2|
|1         |20170319|      error1|
|2         |20170319|        err6|
|1         |20170319|       error2|
```

Need the number error counts day wise

output

```
+----------+--------+------------+
|    date|       errors| count
+----------+--------+------------+
 |20170319|      error1|    2
 |20170319|      error2|    3
 |20170319|        err6|    1
```

```
    val dataset = spark.read.json(path);
    val c =dataset.groupBy("date").count()
```

//how I proceed to count errors

I tried Windowing over date in spark scala sql but not able find productive
do  i need to convert to Rdd and find a approach.?

Comment: Try changing `groupBy("date")` to `groupBy("date", "errors")`

Comment: yes that worked..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `groupBy` both `date` and `errors`.

```
val c =dataset.groupBy("date","errors").count()
```